# How to filter last 12 hours items from list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

I am working on Angular. I have data in `json` format from and I want to filter items of last 12 hours from current date time, based on `LastSeen` field of data

This is my data

```
{
    "Products": [
        {
            "ProductID": "8",
            "UserName": "User north",
            "Date": "08/22/2018 09:58:09",
        },                      
        {
            "ProductID": "732",
            "UserName": "Ser",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 22:31:26",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "733",
            "UserName": "Zte",
            "Date": "07/29/2020 22:53:31",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "734",
            "UserName": "Rck",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 18:01:04",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "735",
            "UserName": "TIO",
            "Date": "05/13/2020 18:53:18",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "736",
            "UserName": "IDO",
            "Date": "07/21/2020 15:51:57",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "737",
            "UserName": "olp",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 15:21:54",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "738",
            "UserName": "oku",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 15:24:09",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "743",
            "UserName": "ijk",
            "Date": "06/16/2020 06:26:30",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "744",
            "UserName": "ojp",
            "Date": "06/16/2020 20:12:29",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "746",
            "UserName": "jpi"
            "Date": "06/19/2020 14:05:43",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "747",
            "UserName": "oom",
            "Date": "06/19/2020 15:30:51",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "750",
            "UserName": "okn",
            "Date": "06/29/2020 17:59:08",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to create an object from your JSON and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the elements you want, along with [Date.prototype.setHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) and [Date.prototype.getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) to calculate the limit time you want.

Worth noting two things:

1. your JSON is missing a comma after the username of ProductID 744 (so I added it);
2. JSON doesn't accept exceeding commas after the last property of an object (so I removed them).

```js
var str = `{
    "Products": [
        {
            "ProductID": "8",
            "UserName": "User north",
            "Date": "08/22/2018 09:58:09"
        },                      
        {
            "ProductID": "732",
            "UserName": "Ser",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 22:31:26"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "733",
            "UserName": "Zte",
            "Date": "07/29/2020 22:53:31"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "734",
            "UserName": "Rck",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 18:01:04"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "735",
            "UserName": "TIO",
            "Date": "05/13/2020 18:53:18"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "736",
            "UserName": "IDO",
            "Date": "07/21/2020 15:51:57"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "737",
            "UserName": "olp",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 15:21:54"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "738",
            "UserName": "oku",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 15:24:09"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "743",
            "UserName": "ijk",
            "Date": "06/16/2020 06:26:30"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "744",
            "UserName": "ojp",
            "Date": "06/16/2020 20:12:29"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "746",
            "UserName": "jpi",
            "Date": "06/19/2020 14:05:43"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "747",
            "UserName": "oom",
            "Date": "06/19/2020 15:30:51"
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "750",
            "UserName": "okn",
            "Date": "06/29/2020 17:59:08"
        }
    ]
}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date(now.setHours(now.getHours() - 12));

var last12Hours = obj.Products.filter(p => new Date(p.Date) >= then);

console.log(last12Hours);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this will help you!

```js
const data = {
    "Products": [
        {
            "ProductID": "8",
            "UserName": "User north",
            "Date": "08/22/2018 09:58:09",
        },                      
        {
            "ProductID": "732",
            "UserName": "Ser",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 22:31:26",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "733",
            "UserName": "Zte",
            "Date": "07/29/2020 22:53:31",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "734",
            "UserName": "Rck",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 18:01:04",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "735",
            "UserName": "TIO",
            "Date": "05/13/2020 18:53:18",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "736",
            "UserName": "IDO",
            "Date": "07/21/2020 15:51:57",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "737",
            "UserName": "olp",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 15:21:54",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "738",
            "UserName": "oku",
            "Date": "07/30/2020 15:24:09",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "743",
            "UserName": "ijk",
            "Date": "06/16/2020 06:26:30",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "744",
            "UserName": "ojp",
            "Date": "06/16/2020 20:12:29",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "746",
            "UserName": "jpi",
            "Date": "06/19/2020 14:05:43",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "747",
            "UserName": "oom",
            "Date": "06/19/2020 15:30:51",
        },
        {
            "ProductID": "750",
            "UserName": "okn",
            "Date": "06/29/2020 17:59:08",
        }
    ]
};
const currentTime = new Date();
const before12Hours = new Date(currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() - 12))
const filteredRecords = data.Products.filter(product=>(new Date(product.Date))>before12Hours)
console.log(filteredRecords)
```